# How to make android:versionName in AndroidManifest.xml changed automatically in eclipse?

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-version, auto-versioning

I want to change android:versionName each time when I release apk.

Are there any eclipse plugin or some other ways that can help it automatically change along with my code's compilation?

For example, 
today is 10/09/2011, I want the value android:versionName in AndroidManifest.xml be set to 1.0.0.1009

Comment: I once played with svn $Rev:$ tag but to no avail: could not make it a number. I think only a shell script can do this...

Answer (score 1):

Not using eclipse sorry (but with Ant yes , see [this](http://www.alittlemadness.com/2010/10/05/android-automated-build-versioning/)) , i know it can be boring to do that . But you don't release everyminute , no?

**MODIFIED**

Ant way , the use of [Ant properties](http://ideoplex.com/id/17/using-ant-properties)

Tomorrow i'll try to find more doc about if you need it

Comment: Hi A.Quiroga: Thanks for your reply, but I don't know how to use your tool :(  Could you help me?

Comment: Hi A.Quiroga: Thanks for your help. Now I write a simple ant xml and add it before building android project, but because it will change the   content of AndroidManifest.xml before build which eclipse don't know the change, I will get error message "org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceException: Resource is out of sync with the file system: '/TestAntAndroid/AndroidManifest.xml'.
[2011-10-10 17:38:18 - TestAntAndroid] AndroidManifest.xml does not declare a Java package: Build aborted."